# Rewrite url with directory has two letters

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite or redirect the following link

- http://example.com/cc/anystring

to

- http://example.com/anystring
  cc

is any string has two letters: can be id, it, ca....
I tried to search but not found solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/(.*)$ /$1  [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Davis, how to set redirect from http://example.com/cc/anystring to http://example.com/anystring rewrite seems to be not enough

Comment: I have resolved with RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/(.*)$ /$1  [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

I believe mod_rewrite is what you are looking for.

Here's a helpful article on the subject: 
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Also here is mod_rewrite in the official Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html